# iOS 14 widget has no main() to be launched

Tags: ios, xcode, hyperlink

I'm integrating an iOS 14 widget extension into an existing project with [Buck](https://buck.build/). But after building the whole project by xcode, xcode alerts me with following error message.

```
Details

SendProcessControlEvent:toPid: encountered an error: Error Domain=com.apple.dt.deviceprocesscontrolservice Code=8 "Failed to show Widget '***.***.***' error: Error Domain=SBAvocadoDebuggingControllerErrorDomain Code=1 "Failed to get descriptors for extensionBundleID (***.***.***)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to get descriptors for extensionBundleID (***.***.***)}." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to show Widget '***.***.***' error: Error Domain=SBAvocadoDebuggingControllerErrorDomain Code=1 "Failed to get descriptors for extensionBundleID (***.***.***)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to get descriptors for extensionBundleID (***.***.***)}., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fd129f04470 {Error Domain=SBAvocadoDebuggingControllerErrorDomain Code=1 "Failed to get descriptors for extensionBundleID (***.***.***)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to get descriptors for extensionBundleID (***.***.***)}}}
Domain: DTXMessage
Code: 1
--


System Information

macOS Version 10.15.6 (Build 19G2021)
Xcode 12.0 (17210.1)
```

And I saw another more specific error message in the Run log of xcode:

```
***[84708:4569018] [default] Failed to find the 'main()' function in the main binary.
```

After googling the error above, I think [this thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/651611?page=2) is pointing out the root cause of launch failure of the widget extension.

So I searched the buck scripts on my laptop and remove all **'-e _NSExtensionMain'** linker flags in the buck scripts.

Then I rerun xcode to build the main app and the widget extension, but I still find the link flag **'-e _NSExtensionMain'** in the link command options printed by xcode.

I believe my removal of those link flags in the buck scripts works, because before the removal, there were two consecutive **'-e _NSExtensionMain'** in the link command options, after the removal, I can see only one **'-e _NSExtensionMain'**.

But I don't know why xcode inserts **'-e _NSExtensionMain'** for us, and which flag in the Build Settings or xcconfigs or buck files will indicate xcode to insert **'-e _NSExtensionMain'** for us.

Does anyone know the root cause? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your program is just missing @main before your widget struct.

```
@main
struct myWidget: Widget {
```

Comment: Thanks Ray.
I found the root cause of the run error.
We introduces extra link flags:

"-Wl,-unexported_symbols_list,$(location //Core/Resources/UnexportedSymbols:unexported-symbols.lst)"

After I removed this extra link flag, I could run my widget successfully on iOS 14 devices.